# Jenkins won't start firefox browser (Selenium tests)

Tags: c#, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, nuget

jenkins doesn't want to open a firefox browser.
I have set a pipeline project for C#/Selenium

```
node
{
    stage 'Checkout code'
        git credentialsId: 'somehash', url: 'giturlhere'
    stage 'Restore NuGet'
        bat 'C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/NuGet.CommandLine/tools/nuget.exe restore AutomatedTests.sln'
    stage 'Build' 
        bat "\"${tool 'MSBuildLocal'}\" AutomatedTests.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=\"Any CPU\" /p:ProductVersion=1.0.0.${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
    stage 'Test'
        bat 'C:/ProgramData/chocolatey/lib/nunit-console-runner/tools/nunit3-console.exe AutomatedTests/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/AutomatedTests.dll --where "cat == DCG"'
    
}
```

Jenkins will process everything, go through all the steps and end up with a mistake in a few minutes in the test phase itself. When the firefox browser just doesn't open. If I run the same thing in cmd, firefox will open fine and the tests will run, according to which I assume that there will be a problem somewhere in jenkins.

For example i have tried this also

```
"C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\nunit-console-runner\tools\nunit3-console.exe" AutomatedTests/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/AutomatedTests.dll --where "cat == DCG"
```

It works in windows CMD but not in jenkins. Again it wont open firefox browsers.

If I just have any clue, there is no error message about that, why it cant open that firefox browser.

Comment: Please include the exception and stack trace if you are getting one. I'm not understanding exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. The problem was in installing jenkins. If jenkins is installed via windows installer, only console output can be performed. If I want it to work with browsers, I need to install it via java -jar jenkins.war